# Instance of the class inside itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I have a class with public methods (not static) that I can't change.
And I need to add some of my own methods that will use the existing public non static methods,

how can I do it in the right way?

Right now, in my own methods I'm creating an instance of my own class to use the other methods, but I don't think this is a good way.

Example:

```
class aaa
{

  public string a(int i)
  {
    ...
  }
  public string b (int i)
  {
    ...
  }

  public static void x()
  {
    aaa myclass = new aaa();
    string str = myclass.a(5);
  }

}
```

Comment: And why can't the new method(s) you add be non-static as well?  Also, are you really sure you want to create an instance just to discard it?  That would mean the state of the other objects isn't really used, and that the older methods really *should* have been static, but aren't.  If the state matters you probably would want to pass in the instance as a parameter.

Comment: I want to access them directly from another place, without creating instances of this class, just write aaa.x

Comment: Well, by definition, it's impossible to call an instance method without an instance of the type.  That's just fact.  So yes, you'll need to create an instance somewhere if you can't change it at all.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you unable to change your class(because the code you've posted would suggest that you **are** able to change the class.  Are you simply unable to change the methods?  why can't you change them?

Comment: Can't change the existing methods... because there are too many connections etc. Everything works... I just want to know if there is a better way of doing it

Comment: @SamIam it being a breaking change with a lot of dependencies is a pretty understandable reason to not change it.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't trying to accuse him of anything, I was just trying to fish for some more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you really wish your instance method was static; it should have been static from the start since it doesn't rely on using any internal state of the object (since your new method isn't being given, giving, or re-using any instance of that type).  You just can't make the breaking change to make it static because there are too many dependencies using it in a non-static context.

If you can't change the method to be static even though it logically is, your solution is indeed the best you can do in the situation.  It's essentially creating a static "window" into the non-static method.

Comment: Tnx for the feedback :) Eventually I ended up spending lots of time to change everything to static with all the dependencies etc, because I didn't really want to keep my previous solution, and none of the other solutions seemed better then what I did in the beginning....

Answer (score 3):

I think your design is not completely correct but if you cannot change your design this might do the trick. Although I also think that this way of working is not the correct way.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MethodA(int i)
    {
        return StaticMethodA(i);
    }

    private static string StaticMethodA(int i)
    {
        return String.Format("i is {0}", i);
    }

    public static void MethodX()
    {
        string str = StaticMethodA(5);
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to do:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
string str = mc.MethodA(3);

//or

MyClass.MethodX();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing looks very much like [*extension methods*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) of C#. Define them in a separate `static` class, and use them as if they were instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

To call non-static method you **must** have instance of class, which instance method you want to call. Also thus you can't change class `aaa`, then you are able only to extend it with [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) or inherit from that class. Here is extension method sample:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void x(this aaa myClass)
    {
       // use public methods of class you are extending
       string str = myclass.a(5);
    }
}
```

You can execute `x` method like a normal method of `myClass` instance:

```
aaa myclass = new aaa();
myClass.x(); // you extension
```

**BTW** in C# we use PascalNames for classes and methods.

Comment: This might be the case if he were passing it in as a parameter, but he's not.  Also note it doesn't really change anything, it just gives the *illusion* of being an instance member.  What he really needs is to make an instance method static, not a static method an instance method.

Comment: @Servy sorry, didn't get you. He is not passing `myClass` as parameter. He tries to call it's public methods. Or I'm missing something here?

Comment: If you forget the extension aspect for a moment (as it's merely how it looks, not what it does) you're suggesting adding a new parameter to the method of type `aaa`.  From what I can gather, it's intentional that that *not* be a parameter.  He doesn't *want* to pass one in, nor does he want the method to seem like an instance method.  That's my interpretation of the problem anyway.

Comment: @Servy OK, I see your point. But I think that extension is what OP needs here

Comment: Why?  If my interpretation of the problem is correct and he has an instance method that should be static, rather than a static method that should be an instance method, then an extension method won't help at all.  It's literally the exact opposite of what he wants.  If he wanted a new instance method he'd just add a new instance method.  He doesn't want that.

Comment: When you say, "I see your point" it would indicate that you either agreed with the point, or at least felt it was reasonable probable.  What's your reasoning for thinking he needs an extension method?  If he wanted the new `x` method to be an instance method he'd just make it an instance method, rather than an extension method.

Comment: @Servy my reasoning is above - 1) he can't change class. 2) He want's to call it's public instance methods. Thus he 1) should create other class or extension 2) should have instance of class. Which brings me to extending instance of class with extension. methods. Another option is inheriting. BTW there is no mention that he wants static method. It's just current implementation

Comment: But he *can* change the class.  He just can't change the signature of the existing methods because that would be a breaking change for his code.  He can add new methods if he wants.  What he can't do is change `a` to be static, even though it logically should have been static from the very start.  He's wondering how he can address this design flaw to create a new static method that performs the actions in the method `a` without breaking all of the existing code that calls the `a` method.

Comment: @Servy 'I have a class with public methods (not static) that I **can't** change.' That's what he wrote. Anyway I don't see any reason for arguing here about what OP really wants. If you are right, he will mark your answer as correct

Comment: See the comments on the question itself.  He *was* able to add the method `x`, so clearly he can modify the class.  It's the method in the class that he can't change.  When Sam posted your assertion as a question the OP clarified that he can add new methods to the class, but that he can't change the signature of the existing methods because it would break all of the existing code calling those methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is where inheritance becomes useful. The syntax for this in c# is:

```
public class myClass : aaa
{
```

Then all you have to do is put your methods in this class. The other methods will work just as well.

Comment: What do I gain from it? everything works anyway, I'm just looking for a more "correct" way

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the class use extension methods.
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Don't write static method:

```
class Other {
  private aaa _MyClass = new aaa();
  public void x() {
    string str = _MyClass.a(5);
  }
}
```

Declare aaa as static instance:

```
static aaa s_MyClass = new aaa();
public static void x() {
  string str = s_MyClass.a(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact Use Case for Extension Methods imho.

You need to attach behaviour (new methods) to a closed class right. So just go:

```
class aaa
{
  public string a(int i)
  {
    ...
  }
  public string b (int i)
  {
    ...
  }
}

static class ExtensionContainer
{
  public static void x(this aaa myclass)
  {
    string str = myclass.a(5);
  }
}
```

The extension method(s) will be callable just like instance methods, so the caller provides the object needed for the functions you need to use.

If you actually have a requirement to have the new method be static - that's just a huge code smell. Static methods being closer to pure functions - and using an internal stateful object for implementation?

If it's NOT a sign of bad design, i don't know the siutation, just make a singleton of your class (aaa) and use that object for implementing the method.